# HTML and PHP login form wont redirect or show any error(when i insert a wrong password)

Tags: php, sql

I tried to create a login form for my school assignment. but in the login form that I created using php,html it wont display me a error when I enter a wrong username and password and also it wont redirect me to the page (users.php) where it is supposed to be redirected.

I have created a database called wad and it has a table called login which has 4 columns namely id,username,password,type(type of user whether admin, user)
. but here I didn't consider about the type of user although there is a column

here is the sql code of the database:

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jun 19, 2018 at 08:24 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.2.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `wad`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `login`
--

CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('Admin','User') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'User'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `login`
--

INSERT INTO `login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 'ASHEN', 'ASHEN', 'Admin');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `login`
--
ALTER TABLE `login`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `login`
--
ALTER TABLE `login`
  MODIFY `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Pls explain me where I have gone wrong and where I can improve
please ignore any errors that I have done when posting the question since I am a newbie

html and php code :

```
<?php require_once('connection.php');?>
<?php
//check for form submission
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $errors=array();
    //check if the username and password is correct
    if(!isset($_POST['username']) || strlen(trim($_POST['username']))< 1){
        $errors[]='Username is invalid or missing';
    }
     if(!isset($_POST['password']) || strlen(trim($_POST['password']))< 1){
        $errors[]='password is invalid or missing';
    }
    //check any errors for any form error
    if(empty($errors))
    {
     // save username and password into variable
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);

    //prepare database query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username ='{$username}' AND password ='{$password}' LIMIT 1";

        $result_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if ($result_set)
        {
            //query successful
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result_set)==1)
            {
                  //redirect to the users.html

                // check whether the user is valid
                //valid user is forund
                header('Location:users.php');

            }
            else
            {
                //invalid username and password
                $errors[]='Invalid Username or password';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errors[]='database query failed';
        }



    //display error   
    }

}



?>


<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login windows</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style4.css">
<body>
    <div class="loginbox">
        <img src="img/avatar.png" class="avatar">
        <h1> Login </h1>

            <?php
            if(isset($errors) && !empty($errors))
            {

                echo '<P class="error">Invalid username or password</P>';

            }

            ?>
        <form>
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" ><br>
            <a href="#" >Forgot password </a>

        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
<?php mysqli_close($connection) ?>
```

css code:(in the html code I have created a file called style4.css and linked it)

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) ,url('img/bg1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-blend-mode: soft-light;
    font-family: sans-serif;

}

p.error
{
    background: :red  ;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.loginbox{

    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 70px 30px;

} 

.avatar{

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);


}

h1
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;



}

.loginbox p{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.loginbox input{

    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.loginbox input[type="text"],[type="password"]
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;

}

.loginbox input[type="button"]
{
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="button"]:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ffc107;
    color: #000;
}

.loginbox a{

    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.loginbox a:hover{

    color: #ffc107;
}
```

Comment: You're checking for `$_POST` variables, but your form is `GET`. Also missing a closing `</head>`

Comment: You should never ever never save password in plain text, use encryption

Answer (score 0):

Please change the form as this.

```
<form method="POST">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" ><br>
            <a href="#" >Forgot password </a>

        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping

Answer (score 0):

put method="post" on your form tag, and put space after location `header('Location: users.php');`